# How can I customize the URL in the address bar to display the article title?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to figure out how to modify a URL in the address bar to show a title for an article.

I have a blog with the posts being pulled from the mysql DB and the links to the detailed view of each blog post is generated as `blog_details.php?lesson_id=$articleID`. What I can't seem to figure out is how can I rewrite the url to show `/article-title/` rather than `/blog_details.php?lesson_id=abc` and what to do with the new url when retrieving the contents of the post.

I know that if I use

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog_details.php?lesson_id=$1
```

it'll come up as `abc` but `abc` is not the title of the post, but rather the ID. Would I need to create a separate column in my db and store the `url-article-title` in it and just pass that information off into the URL `blog_details.php?lesson_id=`?

The other question is, in my blog_details.php I'm using if(isset()) {$_GET[]} to retrieve the article ID currently and load the content of the post through that. How would I have to modify the $_GET request to retrieve the new url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the url to be just `/article-title` it would be more efficient to add a "slug" column, index it properly and use that to retrieve the entry.

If you'd be ok with a url like `/article-title/id` you can accomplish that without touching the database. I'm assuming the ID is a number.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ /blog_details.php?lesson_id=$2
```

This is similar to how StackOverflow handles their URLs. You should definitely output the canonical URL on the site to prevent duplicate content because the "title" that's passed won't matter and could get weird. For example: `/some-article-title/123` and `/some-other-article-title-123` would both bring you to `123`.

Comment: This sounds like a great way to do it. I'm just trying to understand how `([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$` would translate to a specific article title? Or am I supposed to generate the url as `/article-title/blog_details.php?lesson_id=` and then rewrite that? As for the ID it's a mix of letters and numbers, like a course code bio_01 for instance.

Comment: Oh, would I need to do something like `blog_details.php?lesson_id=$1&title=$2`? so it'll rewrite to `/ID/TITLE`?

Comment: No, just generate the url as `/some-article-title/id` and that'll match the `^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$` rewrite rule. We're only passing the second capture to the page we're actually loading `/blog_details.php?lesson_id=$2`. The `some-article-title` part is basically just cosmetic.

Answer (score 1):

this is what I normally do in these type of situations.
First of all, **yes** you would need to create a separate column and store the title of the article.
Then, using this rule..you can rewrite this :- **blog_details.php?lesson_id=**  to this :- 
**/articles/articletitle**

The rewrite rule :-

```
RewriteRule ^articles/(.+)$ blog_details.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note :- You would need to fetch the url title via the id.

Comment: How would I fetch via id? currently i use `$_GET['id']`. Would I still use that even though the URL is rewritten and does not have an ID field?

Comment: @Fahad,
In the blog_details.php file, you can get the ID via $_GET or $_REQUEST both.
Please keep in mind, that if you want to display in a manner **/articles/title** , the value passed by **$1** in blog_details.php would be the title itself.So the title column you're going to make should be distinct.No two articles can have the same title.

Comment: @Fahad, All the best.